# Missing Runtime libraries Websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere, cmis, opencmis

I am trying to deploy a GWT application which has CMIS connector to Websphere 8.5.5. I had no issues while running it in Classic Dev Mode (on Jetty) or on a Tomcat Server - both using Oracle 7 JDK.

During deployment to Websphere (uses IBM JDK) I run into this:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.VerifyError
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:61)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:431)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:288)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1111)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:372)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
        at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.getJaxbContext(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:245)
        at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl$1.makeObject(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
        at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.parse(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:158)
        at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.parse(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:128)
        at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.readFromXml(LicenseProvider.java:155)
        at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.get(LicenseProvider.java:123)
        at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.get(LicenseProvider.java:50)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at my.package.core.server.services.i18n.I18NConfigurationServiceImpl.getLanguages(I18NConfigurationServiceImpl.java:53)
        at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.scanPackage(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:150)
        at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:204)
        at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:195)
        at my.package.core.server.schema.CustomSchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(CustomSchemaLoaderImpl.java:71)
        at my.package.core.server.services.SchemaServiceImpl.getSchema(SchemaServiceImpl.java:144)
        at my.package.core.server.SchemaDBInitialize.start(SchemaDBInitialize.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:70)
        at my.package.core.server.LsServer.start(LsServer.java:161)
        at my.package.core.server.AppInitializer.contextInitialized(AppInitializer.java:210)
```

It is not the complete stacktrace - I just included the part where the websphere stuff stops. This line `my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.getJaxbContext(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:245)` simply calls the JAXBContext from `javax.xml.bind`. This goes all the way until com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl which comes from  `jaxb-impl` dependency which is a transient dependency to the `chemistry-opencmis-client-impl`.

These are the dependency declarations from my POM file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
            <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
            <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-websphere</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I did try to compile the project with the IBM JDK.

I think I am probably missing some libraries at runtime but I am not sure which ones and certainly why (as mentioned before I don't have this issue when deploying to Tomcat). I would appreciate any help or hint because I have been struggling with this one for quite long.

Comment: Have you tried the latest OpenCMIS version? OpenCMIS 0.8.0 has been released 5 years ago. A lot has changed since then, including the dependencies.

Comment: It seems to be incompatible with axis2 1.6.2 which was added by someone else to the project, but may be it will be easier to upgrade axis2. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of @Florian Müller worked together with (as mentioned in the comments) upgrading Axis2 to 1.7.5. We then had a lot of VerifyErrors during deployment for conflicting jaxb libraries. Removing all xml parsing dependencies (putting them into provided scope for the WebSphere profile) -
 in our case these were geronimo-stax-api, xercesImpl, xml-apis, xml-beans, activation - finally resolved the issue.